# Polymorphism (inheritance) and value types

Tags: c++, polymorphism, value-type

I have a bunch of types, `PixelMeasure`, `PointMeasure`, `CentimeterMeasure` and so on, that represent a value with a unit. I would like them to have

- value semantics: e.g. effectively immutable, don't have to worry about memory allocation, and
- polymorphism: I can return an object of type `Measure` and can operate on it without knowning what specific kind it is. I would also like to be able to put multiple different `Measure`s into a container.

It seems these are mutually exclusive in C++. For polymorphism, I need to use pointers or references.

I see two options:

- Use smart pointers, e.g. `shared_ptr`. This gives me the behavior that I want (safe, no raw pointers, but polymorphic dispatch). The downsides are:

  - It is verbose (I could hide it behind a typedef if I really wanted).
  - You have memory allocation going on beneath the hood (but the code is not performance-critical and it is hidden away).
  - The semantics is wierd - a copy of my object (`shared_ptr<PixelMeasure>`) will share the same underlying pointer. I can still pretend it to have value semantics - if I make the interface immutable, it shouldn't matter.
- I thought briefly about not using inheritance (there is no common base class) and dispatching via templates - but in that case I need to know the exact Measure kind at compile time, and can't put them into containers.
- I could get rid of the classes altogether and just use one class, with a value and a unit field - but that would be a lot less flexible, and the usage syntax would be worse, so I'd rather avoid that.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about [User defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)?

Comment: User defined literals would give me a nice way to use these in code, but it is 1. only syntactic sugar, the underlying representation is independent, and 2. I rarely create these instances in code. They are parsed from configuration files. What I do is for example convert them to pixels, or display them as-is. There are also more complicated units, like percentage-of-window-height, that take a reference to a window for example.

Comment: Wrap the pointer to the base? Or better yet, have a variant?

Answer (score 8):

You can use type-erase because as Sean Parent puts it, [inheritance is the base class of all evil](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil). He also has a presentation [Value Semantics and Concept Based Polymorphism](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2012/blob/master/fri/value_semantics/value_semantics.pdf?raw=true) which is probably what you want. It is the same idea behind e.g. `std::function`.

Basically, you use sub-type polymorphism through inheritance in an internal class to use everything that maps to a concept polymorphically. Here is an example from [Type Erasure with Merged Concepts](https://aherrmann.github.io/programming/2014/10/19/type-erasure-with-merged-concepts/):

```
class Greeter {
  public:
    // Constructor: We can stuff anything into a Greeter costume.
    template <class T>
    Greeter(T data) : self_(std::make_shared<Model<T>>(data)) {}

    // External interface: Just forward the call to the wrapped object.
    void greet(const std::string &name) const {
        self_->greet(name);
    }

  private:
    // The abstract base class is hidden under the covers...
    struct Concept {
        virtual ~Concept() = default;
        virtual void greet(const std::string &) const = 0;
    };
    // ... and so are the templates.
    template <class T>
    class Model : public Concept {
      public:
        Model(T data) : data_(data) {}
        virtual void greet(const std::string &name) const override {
            // Forward call to user type.
            // Requires that T can greet.
            data_.greet(name);
        }

      private:
        // The user defined Greeter will be stored here. (by value!)
        T data_;
    };

    // Polymorphic types require dynamic storage.
    // Here we store our pointer to the Model that holds the users Greeter.
    std::shared_ptr<const Concept> self_;
};
```

Now, you can put everything into a Greeter object which has a greet method. Other examples are boost::any_iterator or std::function.

You will suffer one memory allocation per Measure value.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty elegant, especially from the usage side. It reminds me a bit of typeclasses. However what's the advantage over just using a smart pointer as a wrapper (besides hiding the smart pointer)? I fear this might be a bit too "clever" and people would not understand the relationship between `Greeter` and `English` (whereas `shared_ptr<IGreeter>` and `shared_ptr<English>` are ugly, but clear). When you have multiple concepts the trick in the last link is very nice of course.

Comment: @jdm If you use a simple smart pointer you need to have a common base class of everything that you put in here. With type-erase, you can use anything that implements the concept, i.e. everything that has the same syntactic interface. As an example, if you have a `std::function<void (int)>`, you can assign a function, a lambda expression or even a Functor object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper class with appropriate copy-constructor and a pointer to your Measure as a field. You'll probably need to add clone method to Measure.

```
class MeasureWrapper
{
public: 
    MeasureWrapper(const MeasureWrapper &measureToCopy)
    {
        m_measure = measureToCopy.m_measure->Clone();
    }

    MeasureWrapper(Measure *measure) : m_measure(measure)
    {
    }

    ~MeasureWrapper()
    {
        delete m_measure;
    }

    // Wrap Measure interface here and call m_measure methods...       
private:
    Measure *m_measure;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variant type for this: it avoids dynamic allocation, but makes polymorphic dispatch more complicated.

See [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html), and there's hopefully a standard version on the horizon.

Alternatively, you can write a more specific discriminated union, providing a nice specific polymorphic-style interface