# invalid covariant return type, nested class c++

Tags: c++, virtual, covariance, covariant-return-types

I have a first class A that contain an iterator nested class with virtual methods:

```
template <typename T >
class A {
  public:
      class iterator {
      public:
          virtual ~iterator() {};
          virtual T& operator++();
       };

      virtual iterator begin() const = 0;
};
```

I have a second class B, that override virtuals methods:

```
template <typename T >
class B : public A<T> {
   public:
      class iterator : A<T>::iterator {
          T& operator++() override { 
              iterator p(*this);
              return p; //for exemple
          }
      };

   iterator begin() const override {
       return iterator(this);// for exemple 
   } 
};
```

But when i use B class :

```
B<int> test;
```

I have something like this, compilation error:

```
error: invalid covariant return type for 'B<T>::iterator B<T>::begin() const [with T = int]'
error:  overriding 'B<T>::iterator V<T>::begin() const [with T = int]'
```

How to implements iterator in B class ?

Comment: The technic StoryTeller talk about is called value type polymorphism (used to be called this way) you will find interesting link in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010081/polymorphism-inheritance-and-value-types

Comment: Virtual methods only work withh pointers and references, so returning iterator by value disables any polymorphic behaviour you plan for it (even assuming for a moment such covariant returns by value are allowed).

Answer (score 6):

Co-variant return types have a couple of constraints they need to satisfy according to [[class.virtual]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.virtual#8).

> The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to
>   the return type of the overridden function or covariant with the
>   classes of the functions. If a function D​::​f overrides a function
>   B​::​f, the return types of the functions are covariant if they
>   satisfy the following criteria:
>
> - both are pointers to classes, both are lvalue references to classes, or both are rvalue references to classes
> - the class in the return type of B​::​f is the same class as the class in the return type of D​::​f, or is an unambiguous and
>     accessible direct or indirect base class of the class in the return
>     type of D​::​f
> - [...]

Yours doesn't inherit publicly, so the base isn't accessible. And you aren't returning a pointer or a reference.

Returning a type with value semantics is good! You should not give up on that. You can substitute the attempt at a co-variant return type with the pimpl idiom. Have `iterator` manage a polymorphic "iterator implementation" class via pointer.